# AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'

Tags: python, python-3.x, обучение-с-подкреплением

Не могу подключить LunarLander-v2

```
import gym
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
!pip install box2d-py

import gym

env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v2")
env = gym.make('BipedalWalkerHardcore-v2')
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
```

У меня это сработало.